# concatenate arrays into one array in ironPython 2.7.5 on .NET 4.0

Tags: python, .net, arrays, list, ironpython

In IronPython 2.7.5, I have a function (a backbox designed by others) that return array of string.

The function is called in a loop. I need to concatenate the returned array one by one. The final type must also be an array of string.

**UPDATE**

My code:

```
   def Myfunction():
      in a For Loop:
         data_array = Anotherfunction()
         final_data_array += data_array  

      ThirdFunction(final_data_array) # the final data type MUST be array
```

I do not know how to do concatenation for array.

So, I convert the array to list and then concatenate them.

Finally, I need to convert the final list (holding all restuls) to an array (it must be array because it will be used as input argument to a lib function) in IronPython 2.7.5 on .NET 4.0.

My code:

```
  from array import array 
  tt = ["abc", "def"]
  array(','.join(tt))
```

I got error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 TypeError: expected character, got str
```

For code:

```
 from array import array 
 tt = ["abc", "def"]
 array(tt)
```

I got error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  TypeError: expected str, got list
```

I cannot use numpy and other packages.

Or, how to concatenate arrays into one array ?

I also tried :

```
 array('c')
```

but, it is only for character. I need

```
  <type 'Array[str]'>
```

Any suggestions ? thanks

Comment: ', '.join(tt) 's type is str not array.

Answer (score 0):

array is a object waiting to be instanced, you shouldn't use it

see:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html

if you cant concatenate list with array because are different types

Concatenate a list or arrays is easy, only try it:

List:

```
a = [1,2]
b = [3,'hey']
print a+b
>>>[1,2,3,'hey']
```

Arrays:

```
from array import array
a = array('i') # i = int
b = array('i') # read the table in the documentation for understand ('letter')
a = 1,2
b = 3,4
print a+b
>>>(1,2,3,4)
```

or for 'str'
use array('u') o array('c')

if want as list

```
a = array('c')
a = ['lel', 'hixD']
print a
>>>['lel', 'hixD']
print type(a)
>>><type 'list'>
```

> Note
>   The 'u' typecode corresponds to Python’s unicode character. On narrow Unicode builds this is 2-bytes, on wide builds this is 4-bytes.

Comment: thanks, but, array('c') is only for character.  I need <type 'Array[str]'>.

Comment: i think that could use array('u'),  @Lily

>>>The 'u' typecode corresponds to Python’s unicode character. On >>>narrow Unicode builds this is 2-bytes, on wide builds this is 4-bytes.

Comment: array('u'), I got a tuple, >>> a = array('u')
>>> b = array('u')
>>> a = "abc", "def"
>>> b = "fgt", "typ"
>>> a+b
('abc', 'def', 'fgt', 'typ')
>>> type(a+b)
<type 'tuple'>

Comment: use a = array('c') and then a = ['hiworld', 'xDDD']

Comment: `a = array('i')` and then `a = 1,2` doesn't make any sense.  First you make a 0-length array and call it `a`, and then you make a tuple of length 2 and call *it* `a`.  Why use arrays at all?

Comment: @DSM  I would like to know that too xDD

Answer (score 0):

Join in str:

```
ss = ', '.join(tt) # result: 'abc, def'
```

Initialize array with "char" or "unicode" with the string:

```
s2 = array('c',ss) # array('c', 'abc, def')
```

I do not know if it is what you want.

Comment: please see the UPDATE in OP.

Comment: module array has a specific typecode as you indicated [@Milor123](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4941927/milor123) in the [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html). The module represent an array (or string) of basic values, you should consider module `numpy` or list for your purpose.